# Why does this TS implementation of "prop" work but mine does not?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, keyof

I was looking through some blogs about how to use the `keyof` feature of typescript to implement a classic function in Ramda/Underscore called `prop` which returns the value corresponding to a given key on a certain object.

Example:

```js
prop('length')('hello'); //> 5 | Ramda's curried implementation
prop('length', 'hello'); //> 5 | Underscore and others
```

I ended up with this implementation (similar to underscore's) that does work:

```js
export function prop<O, K extends keyof O>(key: K, obj: O): O[K] {
  return obj[key];
}
```

But when I change it to a curried version:

```js
export function prop<O, K extends keyof O>(key: K) {
  return function prop__(obj: O): O[K] {
    return obj[key];
  }
}
```

I get an error when I try to invoke it as `prop('someProp')(someObj)`; as I hover over `prop` I get an error that says `Argument of type 'someProp' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'` and I really don't know why.

How can I go about this?

**UPDATE**:
Solved! And now these tests pass:

```js
describe('prop', () => {
  test('should obtain prop value from JSON object', () => {
    const author = { name: 'Luis', age: 25 };
    const getAge = prop('age');

    expect(getAge(author)).toBe(25);
  });

  test('should obtain prop value from known data type', () => {
    expect(prop('length')('lovecraft')).toBe(9);
  });
});
```

Oh man, I didn't know Record and PropertyKey existed...

Comment: You're encountering a limitation of TypeScript's type inference system. When using the curried version it's impossible for TypeScript to know the type of `someObj` because the first call-site (`prop('someProp')`) only provides a value of `K`, not `O`.

Comment: Only by using explicit type parameter arguments, but that defeats the point of using type-inference (and TypeScript does not support partial type arguments parameters because it would break the overload resolution system).

Comment: I found this in Ramda's repo - apparently many of Ramda's functions simply *cannot* be expressed in TypeScript (yet!) because TypeScript's algebraic type system isn't flexible enough: https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/2487 - so all you can do is use `any` as a workaround where necessary.

Comment: @Dai yeah I checked Ramda's repo and it used Record, which I didn't even know existed; I swear the first time I tried to use it, my editor complained that it didn't find any type called Record but now it found both Record and PropertyKey :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move object's generic parameter to the second function (where object is provided as a function's parameter):

```
export function prop<K extends PropertyKey>(key: K) {
    return <O extends Record<K, any>>(obj: O): O[K] => obj[key];
}

const someObj = { someProp: 'a' };

const someProp = prop('someProp')(someObj) // someProp is string

// Expect error
const someProp1 = prop('someProp1')(someObj) // Property 'someProp1' is missing in type '{ someProp: string; }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVzFCMAHgGk5QZgUATAZzgAUCxhYBPE4NgPgAoBrLgC44JAJRwA3gCg4cuFGAwkUXEQDy5EJRr0ASsDTRqpADRwAhih58IAIwBWI9WOcBtEgF04AXm5x7BzdBNk8AbmkAX2lpIxRaeFoIAFtgdUdfKTgk1KZCEQByCwK4SIjYnATslOA8sEz8Ql4CnNrmArFeVvSHCQB6Purc5jhMegSoTBQAcxiBuABRcEN4VgIoCvjEmrqARgbmZta9jq6anv7ButYYNjgWneZdkrG4ZLHaKenR3FuWe8kQza+WyMEmMzCpWkQA)

---

`O extends Record<K, any>` constraint prevents passing objects that don't have `K` property

Comment: Clever! I keep on forgetting about TypeScript's Utility types ( https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html )